# FFmpeg hls randomly Killed

Tags: ffmpeg

A hls input stream being copied constantly is being killed around the 3-4 min make. I have checked all logs and there are no errors. Has anyone ever experienced this issue before?

My command:  `ffmpeg -re -i <inputstream.m3u8> -c:v copy -c:a copy -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 12 -segment_list_type m3u8 -segment_time 10 /path/to/stream.m3u8`

Result: `Killed 5479 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:03:39.13 bitrate=N/A speed=   1x`

Comment: *something* is killing it.  Possibly some "watchdog" process (if it's not a box you control), or check `dmesg` as well (which should tell you if the system is killing it because it's running out of RAM).  Good luck!

Comment: Doing a bit more digging: the issue is isolated to servers with Ubuntu LEMP stack. Server logs show no issues at all. Have you ever encountered this?

Comment: Resolved the issue by going from Ubuntu 18.04 back to 16.04 for those who ever encounter this issue.

Comment: Maybe it had more RAM disk or some odd?